How to get all images information from trash bin Using MediaStore in Android
I'm developing an Android application and need to retrieve images that have been deleted and moved to the trash bin. I've attempted to use MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_TRASHED as a projection, but I haven't been able to retrieve any deleted images.
Here is the code snippet I am using:
 fun queryAllImages() {
        val files = arrayListOf<MediaModel>()
        
        ctx.contentResolver.query(
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
            } else {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            }, arrayOf(
                imageData,
                imageId,
                imageDisplayName,
                imageSize,
                imageWidth,
                imageHeight,
                imageDateModified,
                imageIsTrash
            ), if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                "$imageIsTrash = 0 OR $imageIsTrash = 1"
            } else {
                null
            }, null, null
        ).use { cursor ->

            val dataColumn = cursor?.getColumnIndexOrThrow(imageData)
            val nameColumn = cursor?.getColumnIndexOrThrow(imageDisplayName)
            val isTrashColumn = cursor?.getColumnIndexOrThrow(imageIsTrash)

            var path: String? = null
            var name: String? = null
            var isTrash: Boolean? = null
            if (cursor != null) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    path = dataColumn?.let { cursor.getString(it) }
                    name = nameColumn?.let { cursor.getString(it) }
                    isTrash = isTrashColumn?.let { cursor.getInt(it) } == 1
                    
                    Log.i(TAG, "queryImages: $path \n $isTrash")
                   
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }

